# SSL_connect() fails

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I'm having some troubles with `openssl-1.0.1c` in c++, more precisely

> **SSL_connect()** is failing with no reason, and returns -1.
>   **SSL_get_error()** returns **SSL_SYSCALL_ERROR**.
>   **ERR_get_error()** returns **0**.
>   **WSAGetLastError()** returns **WSAEINPROGRESS**.

I'm stuck in this, and i have ran out of ideas.
Is there anybody who can give me some advice on how to debug this?
Any suggestion is appreciated,
Thanks in advance. 
 
This is what i get on the server side 
 
[image] 
This is what whireshark shows
[image]

Comment: What does the documentation says about error -1?

Comment: In case you didn't check, [here is an useful guide](http://xkcd.com/1024/).

Comment: @YSC
For return value < 0: The TLS/SSL handshake was not successful, because a fatal error occurred either at the protocol level or a connection failure occurred. The shutdown was not clean. It can also occur of action is need to continue the operation for non-blocking BIOs. Call SSL_get_error() with the return value ret to find out the reason.

Comment: Does a network analyzer like Wireshark provide any usable information in the packet trace? For example, is a connection to the remote target being made at all?

Comment: @user4581301 i've updated my question to provide more details

Comment: Sadly all I get from that is what you probably already knew, port opened, TCP connection established, no attempt at SSL negotiation, 90 seconds later, connection terminated. Does `SSL_connect()` wait the full 90 seconds before reporting failure and terminating?

Comment: @user4581301 `SSL_connect()` fails immediately, i think on server side the connection is being closed on timeout.

Comment: I'll provide you more details:
this problem comes out on a particular os [ontime rtos](http://www.on-time.com/rtos-32.htm). 
I've compiled the whole library and generated dlls through an old compiler, borland 5.02. I load the dlls with `LoadLibrary()` and get the functions i need through `GetProcAddress()`. Actually i have no problem on my pc with these dlls, i use the same code and they do work fine, while on the other os they don't.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to be much help here. `WSAEINPROGRESS` hints at the program trying to use the socket while winsock is connecting it. If there is an option to build the DLL with extra debugging info (like a verbosity option), I'd turn it on.